# How to upload image in php

Tags: php

I'm new in php and I'd just like to create a simple website, for that I'd like to resize and upload an image to a server. I'm able to resize it but I don't know how to upload it. Here is my code:

```
<td><form action="uploadpic.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" />
        <input type="file" name="user_image" id="user_image" />
        <input name = "button" type = "button" id = "button" 
                          value = "Küldés" onclick="subm(this.form,'_blank');">
        </form>
        </td>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function subm(f,newtarget){
 f.submit();
 }
 </script>
```

And uploadpic.php:

```
$target_path = "images/clients/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['user_image']['name']); 


function resize_image($file, $w, $h, $crop=FALSE) {
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name']);

echo "original width ". $width." height ". $height;

$r = $width / $height;
if ($crop) {
    if ($width > $height) {
        $width = ceil($width-($width*abs($r-$w/$h)));
    } else {
        $height = ceil($height-($height*abs($r-$w/$h)));
    }
    $newwidth = $w;
    $newheight = $h;
} else {
    if ($w/$h > $r) {
        $newwidth = $h*$r;
        $newheight = $h;
    } else {
        $newheight = $w/$r;
        $newwidth = $w;
    }
}
 echo "new width ". $newwidth." height ". $newheight;
//$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
//imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

return $dst;
}

function print_var_name($var) {
foreach($GLOBALS as $var_name => $value) {
    if ($value === $var) {
        return $var_name;
    }
}

return false;
}

$img = resize_image($target_path, 50, 50);

if(move_uploaded_file(print_var_name($img), $target_path)) {
echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['user_image']['name']). 
"Image has been uploaded";
} else{
echo "Not uploaded because of error ".print_var_name($img)['error'];
}
```

After I did a `var_dump($_FILES);` I got this:

`array(1) { ["user_image"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(10) "000oks.jpg" 
["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpt7HaO1"
["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(606917) } }`

The resize funciton is works fine after that I have created a new variable and another funciton to get name of the variable. In `move_uploaded_file` the first parameter has to be a string: the name of the file which is now `img` and the second parameter is the path. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry but what's the use of `print_var_name`? **You** set the variable, then you should know what your variables are called. It's absolutely bad practice.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_FILES);` and add the output to your question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I have added the output.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect `resize_image` to return, but it obviously doesn't return the file path. I suggest you to go back to the sketch board and think your script over again. It's heavily flawed.

Comment: I expect an image resource file. I have the file path. When I'm using `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['name'], $target_path)` then the image is uploaded to the server but not in the correct size.

Comment: You get just an empty GD resource, nothing else. You don't resize anything - nothing at all. You just make a GD resource and return it. And then you expect that this magically creates a file. I'm sorry but you need to read some more tutorials.